# Eagle - unabled to remove components in PCB view after removal in schematic

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, layout

my schematics and board is completely out of sync and I'm trying to fix it. The error it gives are shown as following:

[image]

[image]

I want to solve this, and doing a little research I'm having this really unfortunate conclusion that I have to keep deleting things, everything, till the two matches perfectly, which is the last thing I want to do and everything I try to avoid, in Altium Designer, you can easily update either one based on the other with a click of a button, so I expect Eagle to have something similar, granted it would be much less convenient, but there should be a way other than keep removing things isn't there?

Or the entire software will fall right into the category of a bloody joke.

Comment: The "instant-sync" behavior of Eagle is actually the only thing I miss when using Altium ;) But granted, you really have to pay attention that fw/bk-annotation is active, otherwise things can get messed up. But it really never happened to me in several years of eagle.

Comment: @Rev: There is really no need to any kind of sync capability in Eagle since you should never get out of sync in the first place.  It used to be easier to get out of sync accidentally in earlier versions, but now in version 7 you have to do something pretty stupid to get out of sync.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: As I said, I never really had any issues with Eagle regarding annotation. IIRC there was a pretty obvious indicator in pre version 7 Eagle as well.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is probably to restore from the most recent backup.  You end up re-doing a hour or two of work, depending on where in you backup cycle you discovered this problem.  However, that's probably less than trying to get a schematic and board back in sync.

It's obviously too late now, but best strategy is to never let the schematic and board get out of sync in the first place.  It used to be easier to do this accidentally, but there is really little excuse for messing this up today.  Whenever you have only one of the board or schematic loaded, recent versions of Eagle put a big yellow warning banner across the top making it clear that any changes made will not be reflected in the other of board or schematic, and that they will get out of sync.  You really should have known you were making changes that would get the board and schematic out of sync.

In this case you only have 6 inconsistancies.  These all are about what net is connected to specific pins.  To clear the errors, delete the connections in both the schematic and the board, then run the ERC check in the schematic again.  It should say there are no errors anymore.  Note that "deleting" a connection in the board means using RIPUP.

Once everything is in sync again, make the connections as you want them in the schematic.  That will cause them to show up as air wires in the board.  Now route the connections in the board to satisfy the air wires.  As long as you keep both the board and schematic open at the same time, there should be no more problems.

Before you get too far, try to think how you got into this mess in the first place.  You had to do something stupid to get here.  Think about what that was so that you don't do it again.  In any case, never ignore the big yellow banner warning you that any changes will get the board and schematic out of sink.